# How to delete a default constraint from a table's Column?

Tags: sql-server

I have altered a table "luAffinity" by adding an additional column "AOTProcessRealTime" to it. I have added a default constraint to the column "AOTProcessRealTime". Below is the query that I have fired:

`ALTER TABLE luAffinity ADD AOTProcessRealTime BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_luAffinity_ProcessRealTime DEFAULT 0`

Now I wanted to delete the column AOTProcessRealTime. For this, I have to delete the default constraint first. So I wrote the following query to delete the constraint:

`ALTER TABLE luAffinity 
DROP CONSTRAINT DF_luAffinity_ProcessRealTime`

On running the above query, I am gettin an error:

`DF_luAffinity_ProcessRealTime is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint.`

However, the constraint has been successfully created but I am not able to delete it. I just wanted to delete the column AOTProcessRealTime. But I am not able to delete it. Am I doing something wrong? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server, your syntax should work. Perhaps there is a subtle typo in the name of the constraint? Use

```
SELECT *
 from sys.default_constraints
 where parent_object_id = object_id('luAffinity')
```

to check how it is currently set.

Comment: Thanks Philip. I found out the problem. The name was stated different when ran the above query